# Tkinter is freezing using for loop to iterate and download files from driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

I use python and selenium to read a text file which contains a more then 2000 of download link of zip files. Then on click of button i want to download files. But when i click button then tkinter freezes and give error of program not responding error. I also use time.sleep(5) methods inside for loop in hope that loop will run in every five second only and prevents from freezing but still no solution.

my function is

```py
        def download_file():
             if running:
                with open('mylinks.txt') as file:
                    for line in file:
                        driver.get(line.strip())
                        time.sleep(2)
                        
                    
 button2 = tk.Button(frame, text = "Start Download", command=download_file)
```

How to prevent it from happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run the function in a thread.

Comment: @acw1668 how to run in thread?

Answer (score 1):

I see you struggling with the same thing for a few days now. Since all of your most recent questions are sort of the same question. I am going to answer them all here.

Below is the whole shot. From clicking the button through downloading all the files to wrapping up. It's all here, with the only exception being that I only marked where you should put your download solution. Other than that, this is ready to go.

You keep being told to use a `Thread`. However, you have 2000 files and I think you really need a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. This code is meaty but decently commented. I would rather you tell me whatever you do not understand (if anything) than for me to write a novel explaining every aspect of this code in detail.

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import concurrent.futures


class App(tk.Tk):
    #adjust these values to suit your needs
    MAX_WORKERS    = 20
    LOOP_INTERVAL  = 100 #milliseconds
    THREAD_TIMEOUT = 2   #seconds
    
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self._close)
        
        #for quitting the threadpool
        self._killswitch = threading.Event()
        
        self._executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=App.MAX_WORKERS)
        
        self._btn = tk.Button(self, text="go", command=self._execute)
        self._btn.grid()

    def _execute(self) -> None:
        #flip the button from "execute" to "kill"
        self._btn['command'] = self._killswitch.set
        self._btn['text']    = 'kill'
        
        #get links
        with open('mylinks.txt', 'r') as file: 
            urls = [line.strip() for line in file if line]
        
        #gather all download processes
        self._remaining = set(self._executor.submit(self._download, url) for url in urls)
        
        #schedule next pool check
        self._sched_id  = self.after(App.LOOP_INTERVAL, self._threadpool, self._killswitch)
        
    def _close(self) -> None:
        #abort next scheduled task
        if self._sched_id: self.after_cancel(self._sched_id)
        
        #set killswitch and run threadpool one more time
        self._killswitch.set()
        self._threadpool(self._killswitch)
        
        #detroy app
        self.destroy()
        
    def _threadpool(self, killswitch:threading.Event) -> None:
        try:
            #gather state of all futures
            done, self._remaining = concurrent.futures.wait(self._remaining, timeout=App.THREAD_TIMEOUT)
            
            #process all completed futures
            while (not killswitch.is_set()) and done and (future:=done.pop()):
                 print(f'success: {future.result()}')
                 
            #if killed, invoke KeyboardInterrupt for cleanup        
            if killswitch.is_set(): raise KeyboardInterrupt
            
        #necessary to capture Cntrl+C            
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            #cancel everything
            for future in self._remaining: future.cancel()
            concurrent.futures.wait(self._remaining, timeout=None) 
            
        #manage progress    
        if not killswitch.is_set():    
            if self._remaining:
                #schedule next pool check
                self._sched_id = self.after(App.LOOP_INTERVAL, self._threadpool, killswitch)
            else:
                #return the button to it's initial configuration
                self._btn['command'] = self._execute
                self._btn['text']    = 'go'
        #finalize kill        
        else: self._executor.shutdown(wait=True)
        
    def _download(self, url:str) -> bool:
        if self._killswitch.is_set(): return False 
        
        #PUT YOUR METHOD FOR DOWNLOADING FILES HERE
        #commented because I think selenium is not a good solution
        #and I also didn't import it or set it up in this example
        #driver.get(url) 

        return True

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Just as a side note: Be careful and try to not call any `tkinter` function from inside `_download` as it can crash `tkinter` and `python` in rare cases.

Comment: @TheLizzard It is not recommended to modify other's code without asking OP.

Comment: It is OK for you, but may not be OK for others.

Comment: @TheLizzard the code is very complicated for me..i'll need to go through it...is there any other solution ? here is my complete code to download files https://www.coderstool.com/cs/krR2Pa

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I am not a programmer myself, i just need this for my one project and i know basics but the above code seems for very advanced user. So I was looking for any solution that could get my project done. I am also learning from basics too.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy and Thank you for your solution. I will look forward to it as well.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy sorry but this wasn't been any help to me. I couldn't understand any thing you have provided as solution to me. This is totally different form what i have in my code.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy i am a learner and what you presented in above code is for advanced user. It is great to see what could more be done using python but my problem wasn't solved. Thank you

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Can you post that code on pastebin and send it to me? I want to see how exactly tkinter crashes.